# Why is updating Spyder to 5.3.3 in Anaconda Navigator taking so long? Is there something wrong?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm updating Spyder through Anaconda Navigator(pressed the gear icon then install a specific version) but it's been going for 4 hours now. I also tried updating it last night using `conda install spyder=5.3.3` but it also took too long and I closed it with ctrl-break. Does it normally take this long or did I do something? Is there a faster method?